# Question about primes and convergent subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a)_{n}$ be a bounded sequence with set of limit points $\{b_{1}, …, b_{k}\}$

Do there exist unique primes $p_{i}, i \in \{1, …, k\}$ suck that the subsequences $(a)_{p_{i}^{n}}$ converge to $b_{i}$ for each $i \in \{1, …, k\}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n=0 $ when $n$ is  prime and $a_n=1$ when $n$ is not prime  then there is not a prime $p$ such that $a_{p^n}\to 0$